# receiving information from server when website is refreshed

Tags: bots, page-refresh

hi i am making an automatic slot booking bot and i want the bot to reload the website every 30 seconds however when pressing the refresh button or ctrl + F5 i am not sure if it is getting information only from the server or also from the cache or dynamic content.

i was wandering if there is any way to ensure all information is coming from the server.

i have tried both ways of refreshing the page yet i am unsure if either of them are actually showing the most recent data after refreshing and whether the information was definitely coming from the server only.

Comment: Please take a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide details (minimal reproducible code example, debugging details, etc) of your approaches, so people can help more precisely. And please use interpunction.